# Implementing claim based authentication in Dynamics CRM using existing WIF STS

Tags: .net, wif, dynamics-crm-2011, claims-based-identity

Does anyone implement Dynamics CRM claims based authentication utilizing existing STS? 
White paper says:

User authentication in Dynamics CRM 2011 is based on Windows Identity Foundation that forms the basis for claims based authentication, allowing a user to present their identity as a set of claims. In this type of scenario, a Security Token Service actually performs authentication, rather than Dynamics CRM. This standardization of authentication mechanism allows Dynamics CRM 2011 to become easier to implement within infrastructures that leverage multiple authentication mechanisms, including third‐party SAML compliant providers

But I cannot find any reference document how to accomplish it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeap other, we have existing app that implement STS and we are not using ADFS. We just want CRM to use our STS

Comment: You are looking to configure Dynamics CRM to use a different STS?

Comment: yes, i have existing STS and want CRM to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this [MS White Paper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/02/22/white-paper-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-configuring-claims-based-authentication.aspx)? It goes into detail on what to configure on Dynamics side and ADFS side.